# jQuery FlexSlider Interfering With font-face in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, font-face, carousel, flexslider

Not had a problem like this before

I've been working on the following website — http://bit.ly/1ps6YOw — and have incorporated a FlexSlider carousel like so:

```
$('#photos-ylnm > .content').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    itemWidth: 200,
    move: 1,
    slideshow: 1,
    animationSpeed: 350,
    slideshowSpeed: 1500,
    directionNav: 0,
    controlNav: 0
});
```

But now I see that, in Safari for Mac, the text in the top section of the website briefly fades a little whilst the carousel is animating slides.

I'm completely stumped as to why this would happen, I've looked in the Inspector to see if there are any changes to the CSS being made to the text on the fly while the carousel is animated, but they appear to stay the same.

Could this be some kind of performance issue?

Here is an image showing how the text differs, quite noticeable:

[image]

Comment: hmmm I can *kind of* fix it with `html, input, select { -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; }` but it's not ideal as it makes all the text on the web page harder to read

Comment: what I find particularly strange is that the text within `feed-twitter` seems unaffected by all of this